# Scifi Movie Group Viewing Event! July 2015!! Coming Soon!

Tags: discussion

After the runaway success of our Spaceballs Group Viewing Event last night (7 active participants and around 10 lurkers (read the Transcript [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198/2015/7/16/22-24)) we're going to be doing it all over again next week!

Have your say on our **next choice of movie**! Have you got a favourite film you'd love to <s>inflict on</s> share with community?

<s>All</s> Most suggestions will be considered  carefully, with <s>no exceptions</s> very few exceptions.

UPATE: Shaun of the Dead and Invasion of the Body Snatchers were our joint-winners and will be played over consecutive weeks.

[image]

Comment: SPOILER ALERT: I think I saw this. Is this the one where he has to train himself to not feel fear? If he does then he's invisible to these aliens, and he and his dad crash land on earth?

Comment: @JMFB - Yeah, we're not gonna be watching this :-(

Comment: I've marked Body Snatchers as the winner but it was in fact a tied-result. Next week's will be Shaun of the Dead.

Comment: You might want to change the accepted answer to the next scheduled movie (and maybe delete the previously scheduled one to keep the voting thread clean).

Comment: @TARS - Good thinking Batman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Shaun of the Dead* comes to mind.

Comment: I love this film.

Comment: I like this film, but have seen it too many times too recently.

Comment: It cannot be watched too many times.

Comment: I love this movie, but I have to agree with everyone else - we've all seen it a billion times.  I would be more receptive to *The World's End*.

Comment: @WadCheber Which is much more related to sci-fi than *Shaun of the Dead* is, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I can't help but put in a vote for *Invasion of the Body Snatchers* (1978).

[image]

[image][image]

There are some genuinely creepy happenings in this film.  Apart from the classic "caper vs. rat turd" debate in the French restaurant, the film has both **Jeff Goldblum** *and* **Leonard Nimoy**.  What's not to love?

Comment: AND Donald Sutherland - don't forget Donald Sutherland!

Answer (score 2):

*Alien* is always a winner as well.

Comment: I can't sit through an hour and a half waiting for that damn thing to come out of his stomach.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like us to watch the Director's Cut of the classic James Cameron film "[Aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_(film))"

[image]

This movie (and especially the Special Edition, sans studio interference) represents the very *pinnacle* of his illustrious career, before he decided to become a peddler of low-grade [smurf pornography](http://www.avatarmovie.com/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes to the original, 1951 version of the science fiction classic *The Day the Earth Stood Still*, starring Michael Rennie and Patricia Neal.

[image]

This is the source of the iconic line, "Klaatu Barada Nikto", which has been used in dozens of other science fiction and horror films.  It is rightly regarded as one of the greatest movies of the genre.  It's also very easy to find.  You have no business saying you are a sci fi fan if you haven't seen this movie.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

IF we're going *classic*, which is what it seems like, then how about ***"The Omega Man"*** with Charlton Heston?

A lot of you may not have seen it but it was what the Will Smith movie "*I am Legend*" is based on. It's the original and **pretty damn good**.

Comment: *Soylent Green is People...* Wait. What? Yeah, *Omega Man* is a classic. +1

Comment: HA @MajorStackings They're PEOPLE, we're eating PEOPLE!

Comment: @Richard why would I get two downvotes for Omegaman? It's a great film. I didn't downvote anybody elses selections here. It's crazy how this place works sometimes.

Comment: @JMFB - Meta works differently than the main site. Downvoting here just means "I don't agree".

Comment: @Richard A fact that sadly the tooltip popups - *This answer is (not) useful* - do not reflect, but I am guessing that is a global setting that cannot be helped. Would be great if only on Meta they would say: *I (don't) agree*

Comment: Will Smith's *I Am Legend* is  based off the book by Richard Matheson. *The Omega Man* is based off the same book.

Comment: @phantom42 - And neither of them do justice to the original story.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mr. Nobody]

How about a movie that is not a classic (yet, although a cult classic according to Wikipedia)?

I haven't seen *Mr. Nobody* yet, so all I have to go by are its reviews, which seem favourable. It is on Netflix (at least in the Netherlands).

Comment: I don't know anything about this film, but it has my +1 based on the film cover. Intriguing.

Comment: @Richard it is odd to say the very least. Literally everything about it becomes ambiguous and there isn't anything in the entire movie you can't argue didn't actually happen. It reminded me of Stay (2005). It is primarily about branching timelines from small choices but is far more about the emotion and character development elements than anything truely Sci-Fi.  I kind of liked it but there isn't anyone I know who I would recommend it to. Might be worth watching to judge Leto's (good) peformance as he is the new Joker.